# Non blocking stream that supports seek from http response in Python

Tags: python, http, io, stream, nonblocking

I have an http response from urllib

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
```

Eventually, I want to be able to `seek()` within the response (at least to the beginning). So I want to be able to have code like this:

```
print result.readline()
result.seek(0)
print result.readline()
```

The simplest solution to this problem is `StringIO` or `io.BytesIO`  like this:

```
result = io.BytesIO(response.read())
```

However, the thing is that the resources I want to request tend to be very large and I want to start working with them (parse...) before the whole download is finished. `response.read()` is blocking. I'm looking for a non-blocking solution.

The ideal code would `read(BUFFER_SIZE)` from the resource and whenever more content is needed, just request more from the response. I'm basically looking for a wrapper class that can do that. Oh, and I need a file like object.

I thought, I could write something like:

```
base = io.BufferedIOBase(response)
result = io.BufferedReader(base)
```

However, it turns out that this does not work and I have tried different classes from the [io module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) but couldn't get it working. I'm happy with any wrapper class that has the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own wrapper class which preserves the first chunk of data. This way I can seek back to the beginning, analyze the encoding, file type and other things. This class solves the problem for me and should be simple enough to adapt to other use cases.

```
class BufferedFile(object):
    ''' A buffered file that preserves the beginning of a stream up to buffer_size
    '''
    def __init__(self, fp, buffer_size=1024):
        self.data = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.fp = fp
        self.offset = 0
        self.len = 0
        self.fp_offset = 0
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size

    @property
    def _buffer_full(self):
        return self.len >= self.buffer_size

    def readline(self):
        if self.len < self.offset < self.fp_offset:
            raise BufferError('Line is not available anymore')
        if self.offset >= self.len:
            line = self.fp.readline()
            self.fp_offset += len(line)

            self.offset += len(line)

            if not self._buffer_full:
                self.data.write(line)
                self.len += len(line)
        else:
            line = self.data.readline()
            self.offset += len(line)
        return line

    def seek(self, offset):
        if self.len < offset < self.fp_offset:
            raise BufferError('Cannot seek because data is not buffered here')
        self.offset = offset
        if offset < self.len:
            self.data.seek(offset)
```

Comment: 1. You use `readline()` which could potentially read the whole response if there are no line breaks in it. 2. You should check if size of already saved data **plus** the size of the line to be saved doesn't exceed `buffer_size` otherwise you risk buffering more than `buffer_size`.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost Thank's for pointing that out. The code is not complete and is certainly not safe. It's missing read() and also does not support responses from the requests module. However, it serves the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library you can iterate over response which is being [streamed](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests):

> To use the Twitter Streaming API to track the keyword “requests”:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',
    data={'track': 'requests'}, auth=('username', 'password'), stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: # filter out keep-alive new lines
        print json.loads(line)
```

To be able to seek you have to save data you've already iterated (read).

Comment: That does not answer my question since there is no support for `seek` and does return a file like object.